# PostgreSQL - pgloader installation in OS X

Tags: macos, postgresql, installation

Granted... this is a dumb question, but it's still a mystery to someone like me, whose never done it before...  I'm trying to install pgloader, but I can't seem to find any documentation....  I'm running MAMP on MAC OS X.  I've already installed the tcllib, and am about to do:

wget http://pgfoundry.org/frs/download.php/233/pgloader-1.0.tar.gz
tar zxvf pgloader-1.0.tar.gz

I'm wondering what directory I need to actually untar pgloader into?  Is there anything else that I need to do to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could gather (YMMV):

You can always do

```
tar xzvf pgloader-1.0.tar.gz
```

(for any tar archives) to see what's in.

If python is setup you should be able to use from the created folder.

If you intend to import or run from anywhere then make sure its on pythons path.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me out...  I'm stuck again...  Apparently, I need to have Pgtcl installed.... So, I installed macports and then I installed Pgtcl, and I wound up untarring pgloader into /usr/local/src....  But, when I try to run it, I just get this:


Cannot load PostgreSQL DB support: can't find package Pgtcl
Make sure the shared libpgtcl is installed properly

I thought that by using MacPorts, this was all handled?  Do I need to do someting in postgres to get it to work?

Comment: sorry I am not on mac, but are you sure about pgtcl? i never saw any dependencies on tcl in install instructions... You do need to have python database driver for postgres (psycopg2), but that was it for me.

Answer (score 4):

There's a much easier way: install [the Mac package](http://pgloader.io/files/pgloader-3.0.99.pkg) from the [downloads page](http://pgloader.io/download.html).

**Update**

This appears to have changed. You can now install it using [homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
brew install pgloader
```

Comment: "Binary build are available on distributions where pgloader is packaged, which currently includes only debian and apt.postgresql.org which covers both debian and ubuntu Operating Systems."

Answer (score -1):

Here's an even simpler explanation of installing Pgloader using [brew](http://brew.sh/):

http://macappstore.org/pgloader/